# Create for statements for each spaces in string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Might be a noob question, but how could I make a for statement for each spaces in a string?

```
text = "Hello World, this is a string!"
for spaces in text
    # do blah blah
```

Comment: Do you want to iterate over the *spaces* or *words*? What should be the content of `spaces` at each step?

Comment: I want to count how many spaces are in a string.

Comment: How about `text.count(' ')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take each character in the for loop and check it is space or not with if the condition

```
text = "Hello World, this is a string!"
for character in text:
 if character == " ":
    # do blah blah
```